# Visual Studio 2010 C++ unwanted whitespace automatically added

Tags: visual-studio-2010, whitespace

I figured this was the best place to ask.

In visual studio 2010 c++, the IDE automatically fills every line where I don't have text with white space. This makes it difficult, when I click on white space it puts my cursor directly where I clicked because there is white space across every line that I make. Is there a way to turn this behavior off?

Every search I have tried comes up with people asking about how to toggle the visualization of white space, so it makes it difficult to find the correct answer. This makes using the IDE difficult, and this behavior does not happen when I use vs2008. To be honest, I did make some IDE option changes but I don't think anything that would cause this.

To be complete, I do not think it will matter, the two VS2010 addins I currently have installed are AnkhSVN and QT 4.7.1 addin.

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW I don't see this behaviour in VS2010. I'm running ReSharper as an add-in only.

Comment: This is weird, all good IDE's should do that automatically. I know VS2008 does for C#. Maybe C++ support just suck as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the setting that you've somehow turned on is "Virtual Space".

It's a setting available in the Tools -> Options dialog, under Text Editor / <Language, in this case C/C++> / General.

Here's a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/02/28/understanding-virtual-space-vstipedit0023.aspx) about it also.

Comment: Perfect. Hopefully this helps somebody else.